# url encode matched groups

Tags: java, regex, urlencode

I've got a regex that's matching a given pattern(obviously, thats what regex's do) and replacing that pattern with an anchor tag and including a captured group. That part is working lovely.

```
String substituted = content.asString().replaceAll("\\[{2}((?:.)*?)\\]{2}",
                                       "<a href=\"#!p\\:$1\">$1</a>");
```

What I can't figure out is how to url encode the captured group before using it in the href attribute.

Example inputs

1. `[[a]]`
2. `[[a b]]`
3. `[[a&b]]`

desired outputs

1. `<a href="a">a</a>`
2. `<a href="a+b">a b</a>`
3. `<a href="a%26b">a&b</a>`

Is there any way to do this? I haven't found anything that looks useful yet, though once I ask I usually find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure 'nough, found my answer.
Started with the code from [Matcher.appendReplacement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Pure java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[{2}((?:.)*?)\\]{2}" );
Matcher m = p.matcher(content.asString());
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String one = m.group(1);
    try {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a href=\"#!p\\:"+URLEncoder.encode(one,"UTF-8")+"\">$1</a>");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

GWT:

```
RegExp p = RegExp.compile("\\[{2}((?:.)*?)\\]{2}", "g");
MatchResult m;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int beginIndex = 0;
while ((m = p.exec(content.asString())) != null) {
    String one = m.getGroup(1);
    int endIndex = m.getIndex();

    sb.append(content.asString().substring(beginIndex, endIndex));

    sb.append("<a href=\"#!p:" + URL.encode(one) + "\">" + one + "</a>");

    beginIndex = p.getLastIndex();
}

sb.append(content.asString().substring(beginIndex));
```

Comment: I actually have to use com.google.gwt.http.client.URL 'cause I'm on the client in gwt, but URLEncoder is what most people will use, so I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all special chars with what you want first,
then match that inside the double `[` and replace it in the `<a href=..>` tag.

That, or extract the url part inside the `[` and pass it through a `URL encoder` before placing it in the `<a href=..>` tag.

Java seems to offer [`java.net.URLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) by default. So I think getting the *url* from the pattern, and passing though the encoder, and then placing it in the `<a href=..>` tag is your best choice.

Comment: yep :P glad you found a solution ;)